# How do I create new field names using values from a list of objects in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

So I have records in a mongo database which are of this format (just an example):

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "some name1",
    description: "some description1",
    parameters: [
        {
            name: "param name1",
            type: "param type1",
            default: "default value1"
        },
        {
            name: "param name2",
            type: "param type2",
            default: "default value2"
        }
    ]
   .
   .
   .
}
```

In my program I am performing this aggregation on the records:

```
{
    '$project': {
        'title': '$name,
        'description': True,
        'parameters': {
            'name': True,
            'parameter_type': '$parameters.type',
            'value': '$parameters.default'
        }
    }
}
```

The result I was ***trying*** to get:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    title: 'some name1',
    description: "some description1",
    parameters: [ 
        {
            name: "param name1",
            parameter_type: "param type1",
            value: "default value1"
        },
        {
            name: "param name2",
            parameter_type: "param type2",
            value: "default value2"
        }
    ]
 }
```

***Instead*** I got:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    title: 'some name1',
    description: "some description1",
    parameters: [ 
        {
            name: "param name1",
            parameter_type: ["param type1", "param type2"],
            value: ["default value1", "default value2"]
        }
    ]
 }
```

All am I trying to do is change the field names for the objects in the parameters list. I have tried looking through the MongoDB docs but I have not been able to find a way to do what I need.

Comment: `parameters` is an array, so if you've multiple records in that, and with your project pipeline they are combined together to give you an array back. add your query with testing data here https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: Yeah, I can see how that would be the case. I am just wondering if there is a way to get desired result, perhaps with an expression or a different aggregation.

Comment: On what logic do you want to pick 1 parameter from the list of parameters?, do you want 1st one from the list ?

Comment: I am essentially just trying to rename the fields in of the objects list. So I want to change default: "default value" to become value: "default value" and type: "param type" to become parameter_type: "param type". So I want the data in the records to stay the same but change the field names. But since the parameters are in a list it complicates things. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, the examples I gave were inaccurate. I have updated the question to show what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$unwind` Deconstructs an array field from the input documents and group them back with desired projection.

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/-pIPbSarfyx

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$parameters"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "description": {
        "$first": "$description"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "$push": {
          "name": "$parameters.name",
          "parameter_type": "$parameters.type",
          "value": "$parameters.default"
        }
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

[$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

[$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.